# nsmutablearray to tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have a nsmutablearray which im trying to display on a table view. i have a uiviewcontroller and added the table view manually. i have added the delegate and source on the xib by draggin it to the file owner. here is my .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>   

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UITextField *texto;
    IBOutlet UIWebView *link;
    //IBOutlet UILabel *links;
    IBOutlet UITextView *links;    
    // IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
    NSMutableArray *jsonArray;
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
//@property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *jsonArray;

-(IBAction)button;
-(IBAction)field;

-(void)populateArray;

@end
```

and here is my .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

NSString *one;
NSString *jsonreturn;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.myphpfile.com"];
    jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url]; // Pulls the URL
NSLog(jsonreturn); // Look at the console and you can see what the restults are
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    NSError *error = nil;
    jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];

    NSLog(@"jsonList: %@", jsonArray);

    if(!jsonArray)
    {
        NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON:%@", error);
    }
    else
    {
        // Exception thrown here.
        for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", item);
        }
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{    
    return [jsonArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell==nil) 
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSLog(@"Im HERE!!!");

    cell.textLabel.text = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"Cell is %@", [jsonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    return cell;
}
```

my question is, i cant get the cells to show the date, i have the ns logs and it shows that it is pulling it, also im getting a thread 1, breakpoint 1.1 error where the the cell is created and a warning on the same line sayin tableView is local and hiding instance variable, any thoughts? thanks for the help!

update:
I got my program to compile but it throws an exception: 
2013-03-26 22:28:48.691 Hello[79888:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

does this have to do with the information im givin the table or im creating the table wrong? thanks again!

Comment: Are you using a storyboard with dynamic prototypes for your table view? If so you don't need the cell = bit and that code will be overwritten by your storyboard.

Comment: For one thing, you don't call [tableView reloadData] after your download. Also, you really shouldn't perform the download on the main thread. I don't know why you get the error. You should post the actual error rather than paraphrasing.

Comment: im still new at this where would i add the tableView reloadData? and also its not really an error it just stops the application saying breakpoint 1.1 but no error

Comment: also im not using a story board im using a regular view and added a tableview on the xib

Comment: Do you have a breakpoint set in your code (a blue rectangle with a point on top of a row number)? you should add the reload data at the end of your viewDidLoad method.

Comment: awesome it compiles now but it give me this error: 2013-03-26 20:15:11.073 Hello[75830:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x71a2010> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key tableView.'

Answer (score 0):

If you've added the tableview through the interface builder/storyboard try adding:

```
@synthesize tableView;
```

under your @implementation in your .m file.  Then make sure you have the tableview connected properly in your IB.  (To the View Controller as both data source and delegate and then form the VC to tableview as tableView.)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *one;
NSString *jsonreturn;
```

The two statements lack  standardization.

If you have not using ARC, jsonreturn will leak.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the warning because you have an instance variable called `tableView` and also inside the table view datasource methods `tableView` is passed in as a parameter. Changing this variable name or the instance variable name would solve the problem. Since they both are referring to the same thing, it doesn't matter.

And if its just stopping at a point saying `Stopping at Breakpoint 1` you probably have set a breakpoint. Its looks like a blue arrow mark , located on the left hand side of the code. You can disable it by clicking on it again(becomes a lighter shade) or by deleting it- drag the breakpoint out or right click on the breakpoint and delete.

[image: Breakpoint]

Answer (score 0):

look at the variable name of your tablview

```
IBOutlet UITableView *tableView
```

its same as in built method of UITableView uses

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

thats why its giving you warning, "tableView is local and hiding instance variable"

to avoid it just change your UITableView variablename to something "myTableView"

Answer (score 0):

First of all allocate your NSMutableArray, Like this " ArrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];